# How to know current position of caret in TextBox(TextBlock) to select a certain word programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, location, caret

For example, when typing in TextBox(TextBlock) C# WPF

beautiful nature

beautiful _ (here, before typing nature, I want to know the index of caret current location. Let's assume '_' underscore is blinking caret now)

What I'm trying to implement is to set startinglocation of selection by pressuring LeftShift button and endinglocation by pressuring RightShift button
so that I can select programmatically the latest(recent) single word only in textBox to be utilized somewhere.

I've been trying several ways with below simple code, but failed and there's no similar case with me on internet..

Or as better solution, is there someone who knows a way that after typing beautiful nature entirely and press some key button only once to select the nearest word 'nature' only programmatically ?

I'd highly appreciate if someone share excellence for this.

```
int startinglocation;
int endinglocation;
int selectionlength;


private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key==Key.LeftShift) After typing Beautiful in textBox,
            {
            
                // To know the current location of Caret, Some wise instruction is needed here

            }
            if (e.Key == Key.RightShift) // After typing Nature in textBox,
            {


                // To know the current location of Caret, Some wise instruction is needed here

                int selectionlength=endinglocation- startinglocation;                    
                textBox.Select(startinglocation, selectionlength);
            }
        
    }
```

---

#### Solved

The latter, better solution to select nearest, latest word only by pressing a key button by Nicolas Tyler. Thank you Mr. Tyler.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.RightShift)
        {
            selectWord();
        }
    }
    private void selectWord()
    {
        int cursorPosition = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        int nextSpace = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(' ', cursorPosition);
        int selectionStart = 0;
        string trimmedString = string.Empty;
        if (nextSpace != -1)
        {
            trimmedString = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, nextSpace);
        }
        else
        {
            trimmedString = textBox1.Text;
        }


        if (trimmedString.LastIndexOf(' ') != -1)
        {
            selectionStart = 1 + trimmedString.LastIndexOf(' ');
            trimmedString = trimmedString.Substring(1 + trimmedString.LastIndexOf(' '));
        }

        textBox1.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = trimmedString.Length;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
TextBox.SelectionStart
```

It gives you the current cursor position where it is when you are using **WinForms**.

When you use **Presentation Foundation** then you can use

```
TextBox.CaretIndex
```

as described in the MSDN [TextBox.CaretIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hello, Storm. I deeply appreciate your idea. But as I already tried and upon my study, the SelectionStart only indicate the starting index of selected text after we've made text selection..I hope to know making selection programmatically by knowing the current location of caret..Now, I've found textBox.Select(textBox.Text(beautiful).Length, textBox.Text(beautiful nature).Length- textBox.Text(beautiful).Length) I need to try this..Utilizing the difference of 2 Lengths..

Comment: When i create a textbox on a WinForm an do a `MessageBox.Show(textBox1.SelectionStart.ToString());` on button click, write a text in the textbox and position the cursor for example aafter the 5th char, then i get 5 returned! This works! When you use Presentation Foundation then you can use TextBox.CaretIndex. This works, too. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Dear Storm, I cordially thank you for your positive support to anonymous person. But, Fortunately, I've found the latter mentioned better solution by Nicolas Tyler and it worked successfully. Please refer to my updated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401068/how-to-get-current-word-at-the-caret-position-from-a-stringtextbox-which-is-ha?rq=1